# Авторские права на Shockwave и Windows Media Player

Tags: авторские-права

Могу ли я сделать бесплатно-распространяемое приложение, использующее в себе windows media player и shockwave библиотеки windows? Не подадут ли на меня в суд и т.д?

Comment: Забыл добавить - приложение опенсорсное

Comment: Вам нужен совет программиста или юриста? Если программист вам посоветует, что можно всё что угодно без проблем, а вы потом получите огромный штраф, кого будем считать виноватым? (А юристов у нас практически нет, у нас не юридический форум.)

Comment: @VladD ну программист может прикрепить ссылку на законы, тексты лицензий и т.п, а если этого будет недостаточно, то затем можно будет обратиться и к юристу. Всё же лучше чем идти к нему с "пустой" головой.

Comment: @edem: Хм, я как-то читал эти самые законы. Они написаны дичайшим канцеляритом, ничего не понятно. В законе не будет скорее всего сказано не в стиле «вы можете линковать DLL X с программой Y», а что-нибудь о «создании производных объектов авторского права с использованием цитирования других объектов», и вам придётся гадать, подходит ли это к вашему случаю. И ещё, что-то я сомневаюсь, что лицензии имеют какую-то силу с точки зрения наших законов — в конце-концов, они написаны на английском.

Comment: @VladD в законе скорее всего да, таких фраз не встретить, а вот в текстах лицензиях вполне. По поводу "силы" лицензий на английском языке. Если коротко, то имеют, как минимум по двум причинам: 1) Международное право, как правило, имеет преимущество над местным законодательством у нас и 2) Россия является участницей "Бернской ковенции" по охране авторских прав.  Так что лучше всё-таки ознакомиться с законами, чем нет, несмотря на их своеобразный стиль изложения.

Comment: @edem: А вы уверены, что лицензии типа GPL имеют силу в рамках международного права, а не только в Штатах? Я лично не знаю.

Comment: @VladD скажем так, нарушать бы её не посоветовал.

Comment: Если что - я хочу использовать контролы axWindowsMediaPlayer и axShockwaveObject  в своей .net Wpf приложении.

Answer (score 1):

Можете. В суд не подадут.

(на самом деле подадут по любому поводу, только если вы вдруг сделает супер-мега-успешное приложение, которое подвинет какого-нибудь крупного игрока с рынка)